# why is my batch if statement not working?

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I have been having trouble with this code for a while. Please take a look and tell me what is wrong so i can fix it. This code will be a part of an xprize competion!

```
echo [Math]
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            Question 1
echo.  
echo.
echo.
echo        If Mary goes to the market and buys three 
echo        bananas for two dollars each, how much 
echo        did she spend altogether?
echo.
echo.
echo        (A) $3
echo        (B) $6
echo        (C) $5
echo        (D) $1
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p ANSWER01=Answer:
cls
goto results


:results
set /a "COUNTER=0"
```

here is what i cant figure out:
i dont know how to change a value of a variable in an if statement

```
if %ANSWER01%==b(
    set /a "COUNTER=COUNTER+1"
)
echo %COUNTER%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the choice command with:

```
Choice /c abcd /m "Answer: "
set ANSWER01=%errorlevel%
```

also for your if statement just do it as so:

```
if %ANSWER01% equ 2 set /a "COUNTER=COUNTER+1"
```

That would be easier and better.

**Note:** the `equ 2` is if you use the `choice` command

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between the `b` and the `(`

AAMOI, `if /i` will make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: @PeterWrite how do i make it so if the user doesn't choose "b" it does "echo %COUNTER"

Comment: Your code works and echoes the value of `counter` (0) if the user doesn't choose `b`. HOWEVER, it's probably better to use `if /i "%answer01%"=="b" (" to allow the user to simply press `ENTER`. Provided the user doesn't TRY to break the program, the code will work quite happily - IF you add the SPACE between the `b` and the `(` as I've advised.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, do need enable a delayed expansion option and give an space to if sentence to a parenthesis:
>
> Your code is something like:

```
set /a counter=0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo [Math]
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo            Question 1
echo.  
echo.
echo.
echo        If Mary goes to the market and buys three 
echo        bananas for two dollars each, how much 
echo        did she spend altogether?
echo.
echo.
echo        (A) $3
echo        (B) $6
echo        (C) $5
echo        (D) $1
echo.
echo.
echo.
set /p ANSWER01=Answer:
cls
goto results

:results

if %ANSWER01%==b (
    set /a counter=counter+1
)
echo %counter%
pause

endlocal
```

Comment: Um, no - not the case. You only need `delayedexpansion` if the variable is altered WITHIN a "block" (a sequence of parenthesised statements) and you want to access the altered value (when you need to use `!var!` instead of `%var%` - `!var!` for the altered value, `%var%` for the value before the block was entered)